# How to use spring data @WritingConverter and @ReadingConverter?

Tags: kotlin, type-conversion, spring-data

I need to make my kotlin entity field (`String`) work fine with DB column `BIGINT`. I believe I can use **spring data converters** for it, but I can't find examples or documentation. Can someone please explain how to use **@WritingConverter** and **@ReadingConverter**?

Without converters I keep getting such errors on save/get operation:
`PostgresqlBadGrammarException: operator does not exist: bigint = character varying`

**UPD**
I managed to configure custom converter:

```
@Configuration
@EnableR2dbcRepositories
class R2dbcConfiguration {
    @Bean
    fun r2dbcCustomConversions(
        stringToBigIntConverter: StringToBigIntConverter,
        bigIntToStringConverter: BigIntToStringConverter
    ): R2dbcCustomConversions {
        return R2dbcCustomConversions(listOf(stringToBigIntConverter, bigIntToStringConverter))
    }
}
```

Custom converters:

```
@Component
@WritingConverter
class BigIntToStringConverter: Converter<Long, String> {
    override fun convert(source: Long): String {
        return source.toString()
    }

@Component
@WritingConverter
class StringToBigIntConverter: Converter<String, Long> {
    override fun convert(source: String): Long {
        return source.toLong()
    }
}
```

But now it tries to convert every String field to BIGINT and vice versa. How can I apply converter only for specific field in specific entity?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I am surprised there is a not a mapping from a Postgres BIGINT to something like `java.math.BigInteger`.  But let's go with your question where I assume you want to use Java/Kotlin `Long` and serialize this to the DB as a String.

Secondly,  I think should be defining 1 `WritingConverter` and 1 `ReadingConverter`, you have 2 x `WritingConverter`.

Here is my working code for a specialised type on the Kotlin side called `RULID` that our MongoDB doesn't know how to handle, so we define a pair of Convertors to read/write:

```
@ReadingConverter
class DBObjectToRULIDConverter : Converter<String, RULID> {
    override fun convert(source: String): RULID {
        if (!RULID.isValid(source)) {
            return RULID.INVALID
        }
        return RULID.from(source)
    }
}

@WritingConverter
class RULIDToDBObjectConverter : Converter<RULID, String> {
    override fun convert(source: RULID): String {
        val h : BigInteger
        return source.toString()
    }
}
```

So the `ReadingConvertor` is about taking a String from the DB and converting to `RULID`, and `WritingConverter` is taking a RULID and converting into a `String` ready to be persisted.  So you need to change `RULID` -> `Long` for your case.

Thirdly, you ask "How can I apply converter only for specific field in specific entity?"

According to a 2021 answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69614213/1847378

> You currently cannot define field specific converters in Spring Data (JDBC or otherwise).

I think you can workaround this by using a Kotlin type alias:

```
typealias BigInt = Long
```

Then your convertors:

```
@Component
@WritingConverter
class BigIntToStringConverter: Converter<BigInt, String> {
...etc
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
Actually my field in DB is **Bigint** and my entity field is **String**, so I guess converters shoul be other way round, so I have something like this: 
`@Component
  @WritingConverter
class StringToBigIntConverter: Converter<StringToBigInt, Long> {
    override fun convert(source: StringToBigInt): Long {
        return source.toLong()
    }
}`, where StringToBigInt is my typealias for problematic field.
But it seems to fail anyway, because it still tries to convert other String fields to Bigint...